# How do I access refs of a parent component in the child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a parent and a child, I have to make sure that the child component that is contained within the father can refer to him.

For example, on the child button I want to call the openDrawer() method, which is used in the parent.

I tried to pass the parent's reference to the child through a props, but it does not work.

Where am I doing wrong?

How can I do?

Parent:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ToastAndroid, Button, Toolbar } from 'react-native';
import NavigationDrawerLayout from 'react-native-navigation-drawer-layout';

import Homepage from './page/Homepage';
import PageOne from './page/pageOne';
import PageTwo from './page/pageTwo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      menu: '',
      type: '',
      drawer: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationDrawerLayout
        ref={_drawer => (this.drawer = _drawer)}
        //ref={(_drawer) => this.setState({drawer:_drawer})}
        percent={75}
        //statusBar="#008cff"
        //statusBarTransparency={0.3}
        type={this.state.type}
        drawerPosition="left"
        selected="opt3"
        window="menu"
        color="#fff"
        backgroundColor="#303030" //303030
        imageBackground="https://c.wallhere.com/photos/aa/44/glare_colorful_bright_circles-679384.jpg!d"
        first={'username'}
        second={'joined'}
        account={[
          {
            username: 'james.bond',
            name: 'James Bond',
            email: 'james.bond.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2-2/512/Casual_Man_2-512.png',
            joined: 'Joined at Jun 21, 2021',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#303030',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
          {
            username: 'sherlock.holmes',
            name: 'Sherlock Holmes',
            email: 'sherlock.holmes.xx@xxx.xxx',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#303030',
            circle: ['#fff000', 'transparent', '#00ffd0'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Shinichi Kudo',
            email: 'shinichi.kudo.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2-2/512/Casual_Man_3-512.png',
            badgeText: '21',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#25dbd2',
            joined: 'Joined at Jun 31, 2021',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Arthur Conan Doyle',
            email: 'arthur.conan.doyle.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-vol-3-12/66/68-512.png',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
        ]}
        badgeFunction={e => {
          return e > 99 ? '99+' : e;
        }}
        menu={[
          {
            type: 'menu',
            name: 'opt0',
            backgroundLarge: 'transparent',
            backgroundLargeFocus: 'transparent',
            backgroundSmall: 'rgba(13, 71, 161, 0.5)',
            backgroundSmallFocus: 'rgba(213, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            iconLeft: 'apps',
            iconLeftColor: '#c1c1c1',
            iconLeftColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            title: 'Le mie app e i miei giochi',
            titleColor: '#000000',
            titleColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#ffffff',
            badgeBackground: '#1194ff',
            iconRight: 'exit-to-app',
            iconRightColor: '#4CAF50',
            iconRightColorFocus: '#EF6C00',
            close: false,
          },
          {
            type: 'menu',
            name: 'opt3',
            title: 'Abbonamenti',
            backgroundLarge: '#4286f4',
            backgroundLargeFocus: '#34ed6b',
            backgroundSmallFocus: 'rgba(213, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            iconLeft: 'apps',
            iconLeftColor: '#c1c1c1',
            iconLeftColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#ffffff',
            badgeBackground: '#1194ff',
            iconRight: 'exit-to-app',
            iconRightColor: '#4CAF50',
            iconRightColorFocus: '#EF6C00',
          },
        ]}
        onPress={e => {
          ToastAndroid.show("Title: "+e.title+" * "+"Name: "+e.name,ToastAndroid.SHORT);
          console.log('Menu:', e);
          var type = e.name == 'opt2' ? 'simple' : '';
          this.setState({ menu: e.title, type });
        }}>
        <Homepage drawer={this.drawer} />
      </NavigationDrawerLayout>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Child:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Homepage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {drawer} = this.props;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          //alignItems: 'flex-end',
        }}>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 25, marginRight: 5, textAlign: 'right' }}>Hello World!</Text>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 25, marginRight: 5, textAlign: 'right' }}>
          State: !
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={()=drawer.openDrawer()}
          title="Open"
          color="#4286f4"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see your openDrawer method in your parent. You also need to provide the Button (grandChild) so that the openDrawer can be set to its onClick attribute.

Comment: can't see  openDrawer method in parent, if it's there then change your <Button onPress = { (e) => this.props.openDrawer(e)} /> in child

Comment: @kev: The module NavigationDrawerLayout inside has that method, if for example I do where the father is:
this.drawer.openDrawer(), it works.

In what sense, I did not understand the second part of the message.

Comment: @Jayavel: I'm not clear the message and use of the props, I need to call the method inside the child.

Comment: For both, I also tried this way:
<NavigationDrawerLayout
....
alert = {() =>
           //this.drawer.openDrawer ()
           ToastAndroid.show ("Alert")
         }>
         <Homepage drawer = {this.drawer} />
</ NavigationDrawerLayout>

Inside the child:
<Button
           onPress = {() => this.props.drawer.alert ()}
           title = "Open"
           color = "# 4286f4"
         />

but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Usually a child shouldn't be aware of a parent. In this case it's not parent (`App`) ref that is passed but `App`'s another child ref, `this.drawer`.

The problem here is that deprecated ref function is used, `ref={_drawer => (this.drawer = _drawer)}`. It results in race condition, since `this.drawer` is passed to `Homepage` before it was assigned with a ref, it's undefined.

It should be:

```
this.drawerRef = React.createRef();
...

<NavigationDrawerLayout ref={this.drawerRef} .../>
...
<Homepage drawerRef={this.drawerRef} />
```

As soon as `NavigationDrawerLayout` is mounted, `drawerRef.current` is assigned with an instance and can be used:

```
<Button onPress={()=drawerRef.current.openDrawer()} />
```

Passing refs breaks encapsulation and provides tight coupling where it could be avoided. `Homepage` doesn't really need the access to entire drawer. This is usually solved in React by passing function prop instead:

```
<Homepage openDrawer={() => this.drawerRef.current.openDrawer()} />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You can pass related method directly to your child. I prefer this.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ToastAndroid, Button, Toolbar } from 'react-native';
import NavigationDrawerLayout from 'react-native-navigation-drawer-layout';

import Homepage from './page/Homepage';
import PageOne from './page/pageOne';
import PageTwo from './page/pageTwo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      menu: '',
      type: '',
      drawer: ''
    };
    this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this);
  }

  openDrawer() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationDrawerLayout
        ref={_drawer => (this.drawer = _drawer)}
        //ref={(_drawer) => this.setState({drawer:_drawer})}
        percent={75}
        //statusBar="#008cff"
        //statusBarTransparency={0.3}
        type={this.state.type}
        drawerPosition="left"
        selected="opt3"
        window="menu"
        color="#fff"
        backgroundColor="#303030" //303030
        imageBackground="https://c.wallhere.com/photos/aa/44/glare_colorful_bright_circles-679384.jpg!d"
        first={'username'}
        second={'joined'}
        account={[
          {
            username: 'james.bond',
            name: 'James Bond',
            email: 'james.bond.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2-2/512/Casual_Man_2-512.png',
            joined: 'Joined at Jun 21, 2021',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#303030',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
          {
            username: 'sherlock.holmes',
            name: 'Sherlock Holmes',
            email: 'sherlock.holmes.xx@xxx.xxx',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#303030',
            circle: ['#fff000', 'transparent', '#00ffd0'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Shinichi Kudo',
            email: 'shinichi.kudo.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2-2/512/Casual_Man_3-512.png',
            badgeText: '21',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#25dbd2',
            joined: 'Joined at Jun 31, 2021',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Arthur Conan Doyle',
            email: 'arthur.conan.doyle.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-vol-3-12/66/68-512.png',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
        ]}
        badgeFunction={e => {
          return e > 99 ? '99+' : e;
        }}
        menu={[
          {
            type: 'menu',
            name: 'opt0',
            backgroundLarge: 'transparent',
            backgroundLargeFocus: 'transparent',
            backgroundSmall: 'rgba(13, 71, 161, 0.5)',
            backgroundSmallFocus: 'rgba(213, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            iconLeft: 'apps',
            iconLeftColor: '#c1c1c1',
            iconLeftColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            title: 'Le mie app e i miei giochi',
            titleColor: '#000000',
            titleColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#ffffff',
            badgeBackground: '#1194ff',
            iconRight: 'exit-to-app',
            iconRightColor: '#4CAF50',
            iconRightColorFocus: '#EF6C00',
            close: false,
          },
          {
            type: 'menu',
            name: 'opt3',
            title: 'Abbonamenti',
            backgroundLarge: '#4286f4',
            backgroundLargeFocus: '#34ed6b',
            backgroundSmallFocus: 'rgba(213, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            iconLeft: 'apps',
            iconLeftColor: '#c1c1c1',
            iconLeftColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#ffffff',
            badgeBackground: '#1194ff',
            iconRight: 'exit-to-app',
            iconRightColor: '#4CAF50',
            iconRightColorFocus: '#EF6C00',
          },
        ]}
        onPress={e => {
          ToastAndroid.show("Title: "+e.title+" * "+"Name: "+e.name,ToastAndroid.SHORT);
          console.log('Menu:', e);
          var type = e.name == 'opt2' ? 'simple' : '';
          this.setState({ menu: e.title, type });
        }}>
        <Homepage openDrawer={this.openDrawer} />
      </NavigationDrawerLayout>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

**Solution 2**

You can use directly `React.createRef()`.

URL: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ToastAndroid, Button, Toolbar } from 'react-native';
import NavigationDrawerLayout from 'react-native-navigation-drawer-layout';

import Homepage from './page/Homepage';
import PageOne from './page/pageOne';
import PageTwo from './page/pageTwo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      menu: '',
      type: '',
      drawer: ''
    };
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationDrawerLayout
        ref={this.myRef}
        //ref={(_drawer) => this.setState({drawer:_drawer})}
        percent={75}
        //statusBar="#008cff"
        //statusBarTransparency={0.3}
        type={this.state.type}
        drawerPosition="left"
        selected="opt3"
        window="menu"
        color="#fff"
        backgroundColor="#303030" //303030
        imageBackground="https://c.wallhere.com/photos/aa/44/glare_colorful_bright_circles-679384.jpg!d"
        first={'username'}
        second={'joined'}
        account={[
          {
            username: 'james.bond',
            name: 'James Bond',
            email: 'james.bond.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2-2/512/Casual_Man_2-512.png',
            joined: 'Joined at Jun 21, 2021',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#303030',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
          {
            username: 'sherlock.holmes',
            name: 'Sherlock Holmes',
            email: 'sherlock.holmes.xx@xxx.xxx',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#303030',
            circle: ['#fff000', 'transparent', '#00ffd0'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Shinichi Kudo',
            email: 'shinichi.kudo.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatar-2-2/512/Casual_Man_3-512.png',
            badgeText: '21',
            badgeColor: '#fff',
            badgeBackground: '#25dbd2',
            joined: 'Joined at Jun 31, 2021',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
          {
            name: 'Arthur Conan Doyle',
            email: 'arthur.conan.doyle.xx@xxx.xxx',
            image:
              'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-vol-3-12/66/68-512.png',
            circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
          },
        ]}
        badgeFunction={e => {
          return e > 99 ? '99+' : e;
        }}
        menu={[
          {
            type: 'menu',
            name: 'opt0',
            backgroundLarge: 'transparent',
            backgroundLargeFocus: 'transparent',
            backgroundSmall: 'rgba(13, 71, 161, 0.5)',
            backgroundSmallFocus: 'rgba(213, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            iconLeft: 'apps',
            iconLeftColor: '#c1c1c1',
            iconLeftColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            title: 'Le mie app e i miei giochi',
            titleColor: '#000000',
            titleColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#ffffff',
            badgeBackground: '#1194ff',
            iconRight: 'exit-to-app',
            iconRightColor: '#4CAF50',
            iconRightColorFocus: '#EF6C00',
            close: false,
          },
          {
            type: 'menu',
            name: 'opt3',
            title: 'Abbonamenti',
            backgroundLarge: '#4286f4',
            backgroundLargeFocus: '#34ed6b',
            backgroundSmallFocus: 'rgba(213, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            iconLeft: 'apps',
            iconLeftColor: '#c1c1c1',
            iconLeftColorFocus: '#4CAF50',
            badgeText: '100',
            badgeColor: '#ffffff',
            badgeBackground: '#1194ff',
            iconRight: 'exit-to-app',
            iconRightColor: '#4CAF50',
            iconRightColorFocus: '#EF6C00',
          },
        ]}
        onPress={e => {
          ToastAndroid.show("Title: "+e.title+" * "+"Name: "+e.name,ToastAndroid.SHORT);
          console.log('Menu:', e);
          var type = e.name == 'opt2' ? 'simple' : '';
          this.setState({ menu: e.title, type });
        }}>
        <Homepage drawer={this.myRef.current} />
      </NavigationDrawerLayout>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: I regret having answered I'm trying both solutions but the second solution I can not make it work: I tried like this:
<Button
           onPress = {() => this.props.drawer.openDrawer ()}
but it does not work: null is not an object.

Comment: Are you using Redux or HOC on Homepage component?

Comment: I'm not using redux, HOC is the first time I hear it mentioned.